# How to define "%{" as string in terraform

Tags: python, string, terraform, devops, terragrunt

I'm trying to add SSM paramater value for aws via terrafom but terrafom consider %{ for defining condition and its giving below error.

> Error:- Invalid template directive; A template directive keyword ("if", "for", etc) is expected at the beginning of a %!{(MISSING) sequence.

But i need this to go as a string for my SSM parameter value for my container to call for their variable.

That's my `terragrunt.hcl`. Can anyone please help me in it?

```
# ONLY FOR THIS DEPLOYMENT!
inputs = {
  parameter_write = [
    {
      name        = "/teamname/${local.common_vars.dns}/index"
      value       = "dev-ws-${local.common_vars.name}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
      type        = "String"
      overwrite   = "false"
      description = "Index"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you provide complete example of you TF code and template?

Comment: Please edit the question with correctly formated code blocks.

Comment: @Marcin - added snip of it

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for code. Please [read instructions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) how to use code blocks on SO.

Comment: You can make use of two functions together. Use the `timestamp` + `formatdate` of terraform https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/timestamp and https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/formatdate

Comment: @SouravAtta - I don't have an issue with a timestamp. I am getting an error due to using %{ together as TF is taking as its expression of defining condition in it, but i need to add a string so that it can be added in SSM parameter value for my container. 

My actual parameter is like to be added below, and it's a pre-defined in container image for pushing logs in elastic search. So can't change this format. Please guide me to how I can define %{ so that it can take as string rather than tf condition function.

"dev-ws-application-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"

Comment: I believe you need to use double `%%` to escape a literal `%`. Just like the documentation states to use double `$$` to escape a literal `$`. https://www.terraform.io/language/configuration-0-11/interpolation

Comment: @MarkB - thanks but getting the same error.
used below:-
name        = "prod-tn-app-dev-%%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"

error:-
 Invalid template directive; A template directive keyword ("if", "for", etc) is expected at the beginning of a %!{(MISSING) sequence.


The actual value I want to add is in SSM parameter:-

prod-tn-app-dev-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}

Answer (score 1):

mark b's answer worked for me:

I believe you need to use double %% to escape a literal %. Just like the documentation states to use double $$ to escape a literal $. terraform.io/language/configuration-0-11/interpolation

Answer (score 0):

would you try escaping the special character using backslash (\)? for example

"dev-ws-${local.common_vars.name}-\%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"

Comment: Clarifying questions should rather be comments on the original question. Once you are sure something works as a solution, post it as a solution